# How to use space for the Item value inside Foreach of Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have "Foreach" which output following Items: 
"Factory Code": "XXXX",
"Factory Name": "XXXXXXXXXX",
"ERP Reference": "XXX",

It has items with spaces, I tried to get the item in the dynamic content with @{item().Factory Code}
However this is not possible as I have space in-between Factory and Code, I can't change the source system. how can I resolve this issue?

See below for the source data send it to foreach

```json
{
    "count": 527,
    "value": [
        {
            "Factory Code": "xxxx",
            "Factory Name": "xxxxx",
            "ERP Reference": "xxxx",
            "Factory Country": "xxxxx",
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by giving the dynamic content as `@item()['Factory Code']` inside ForEach.

Follow the below demonstration:

**My sample json passed to ForEach using lookup:**

```
[
    {
    "Factory Code": "Code1",
    "Factory Name": "XXXXXXXXXX1",
    "ERP Reference": "XXX1"
    },
    {
    "Factory Code": "Code2",
    "Factory Name": "XXXXXXXXXX2",
    "ERP Reference": "XXX2"
    },
    {
    "Factory Code": "Code3",
    "Factory Name": "XXXXXXXXXX3",
    "ERP Reference": "XXX3"
    }
]
```

[image]

Inside ForEach I have used append variable activity to store the `Factory Code` values.

[image]

**Result stored in a variable after ForEach:**

[image]

Comment: Please provide properly formatted text, not images of text. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for many reasons why this is important.